# Visual Studio professional subscription sign-in issue

Tags: visual-studio

Lately, whenever I signed-in to my Visual Studio professional subscription, I've been redirected to this error page: "Got 500 - Something went wrong message. Failed to obtain an application access token using the authorization code.
Does anybody knows how to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on one of the Microsoft's Developer Community Questions, A fix for this issue was released last year, Updating Visual Studio may help in that case.

Have a look on link below.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/670816/500-something-went-wrong-weve-encountered-an-error.html